# Calculate $-\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{B(z_0,r)}\frac{1}{w-z}\mathrm d \bar w\mathrm d w$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-integration

> Calculate integral 
>   $\displaystyle-\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{B(z_0,r)}\frac{1}{w-z}\mathrm d \bar w\mathrm d w$, where $B(z_0,r)$ is any ball in upper-plane, $z\in B(z_0,r)$.

If $z\notin B(z_0,r)$, I can work out it with result $r^2/(z-z_0)$, but if $z\in B(z_0,r)$, the result is $\bar z-\bar {z_0}$, I have no idea how to solve it. Thanks for any help!

Comment: parametrize $w=z_0+\rho e^{it}, z=z_0+|z-z_0|e^{i\alpha}. d\bar w dw=2i\rho d \rho dt$ and split the integral into $|w-z_0| < |z-z_0|$ and$|w-z_0| > |z-z_0|$, using the appropriate geometric series in each case to develop the denominator written as $(w-z_0)-(z-z_0)$, and then you easily get the integrals to be the answer in the first case and zero in the second as the series in $w-z_0$ gives a non zero integral only when the power of $w-z_0$ is zero in it and that can happen only once in the first case and none in the second; could write it up if needed but try do it by yourself first

Comment: @Conrad Thanks for your hint, I will try it later. I worked it out by Stokes and the fact that $\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar z}\frac{1}{z}=\pi \delta_0$.